# Configureing mod_wsgi on Apache2 for Django project

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am having some issues in configuring the various elements of a mod_wsgi setup. This is my fist time using mod_wsgi so I have been following several tutorials, the main one being a YouTube video [Install Django on Apache with mod_wsgi on Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBMVVruB9Vs) . From what I understand after following the below steps I should at least see the Django 'It Works' page.

Setup

- Ubunto 12.04
- Apache 2.2.22
- Python 2.7.3
- Django 1.6

**I have created a WSGI script file firstweb.wsgi in my home directory**

```
/home/firstweb.wsgi
```

Its contents are

```
import os
import sys
sys.path = [‘/var/www/firstweb’] + sys.path
os.environ[‘DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE’] = ‘firstweb.settings’ 
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**I then created a host file for the project located at**

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/firstweb.conf
```

Its contents are

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@firstweb.com         
ServerName www.firstweb.com         
ServerAlias firstweb.com

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/firstweb.wsgi

Alias /static /var/www/firstweb/static/

<Directory /var/www/firstweb/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**I then enabled the configuration file with the command**

```
a2ensite firstweb.conf
```

**I then started my django project.**

I went to /var/www/ and used the Django start project command

```
django-admin.py startproject firstweb
```

**I then restarted my server**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Lastly I then reconfigured my Apache hosts file to point the domain firstweb.com to my new, local, Django project

`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu
134.226.38.147  firstweb.com
```

So with all of this done when I visit www.firstweb.com I should see the Django "It Works!" page

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't listed 'www.firstweb.com' in your /etc/hosts file. Both hosts listed under ServerName and ServerAlias must have a resolvable IP address.